# django query on manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I'm using tastypie to get a REST API for my django application. My models include station (e.g. railway station), route (e.g. Chicago to St. Louis), and routedetail, which is an intermediate model for the manytomany relationship, e.g. RouteDetail(station="Springfield-IL", route="CHI-STL", arrival_time=4.00pm, depart_time=4:05pm)

```
class Station(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class Route(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
  stations = models.ManyToManyField(Station, through='RouteDetail')

class RouteDetail(models.Model):
  station = models.ForeignKey(Station)
  route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
  arrival_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  depart_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My question is how can I query for all routes from Lincoln, IL to St. Louis, MO?
Right now I did something like this in tastypie, which works, but is there a way to do it in one query?

```
from_station = request.GET.get('from', None)
to_station = request.GET.get('to', None)
semi_filtered = super(RouteResource, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)
return semi_filtered.filter(stations__name=from_station).filter(stations__name=to_station)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your model express the existence of a route from A to B? It doesn't look to me as though it includes enough information to be able to tell.

The closest query I can see how to perform is to ask whether there is a route R such that station A is on route R and station B is on route R and the departure time at station A is before the arrival time at station B.

In SQL that would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myapp_route R
 JOIN myapp_routedetail A ON A.station_id = from_station AND A.route_id = R.id
 JOIN myapp_routedetail B ON B.station_id = to_station AND B.route_id = R.id
 WHERE A.depart_time < B.arrival_time;
```

As far as I know there's no way to express this query in Django's ORM, but you can always issue a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/):

```
Route.objects.raw('''
    SELECT * FROM myapp_route R
     JOIN myapp_routedetail A ON A.station_id = %s AND A.route_id = R.id
     JOIN myapp_routedetail B ON B.station_id = %s AND B.route_id = R.id
     WHERE A.depart_time < B.arrival_time
     ''', [from_station.id, to_station.id])
```

But beware: the condition `A.depart_time < B.arrival_time` won't work for routes that start before midnight and finish after midnight.

Comment: you're right I need to compare arrival_time to determine whether it's A to B. I didn't include this since I wanted to focus on reducing the query in filtering the from and to for twice. Anyway, your suggestion for going raw SQL seems to be the reasonable choice if I later found this operation to be bottle-neck. Thanks.